# Display second form if radio button is checked not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have this assignment where I am supposed to display a second form if a radio button is checked.

It is called Piano Festival. The form is supposed to have First and Last name, the student ID of the student, and 3 radio buttons with the options "Solo", "Duet" and "Concerto".

If "Duet" is selected, it is supposed to display the same form next to it, but only with first and last name, and the student ID.

This is my html file:

```
<form id="myForm" action="" onsubmit="validateForm()">
        <fieldset>
            Performance Type:
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="performanceType" id="solo" value="Solo">Solo<br>
            <input type="radio" name="performanceType" id="duet" onclick="checkType()" value="Duet">Duet<br>
            <input type="radio" name="performanceType" id="concerto" value="Concerto">Concerto<br><br>
            First Name:
            <input type="text" name="firstName"><br><br>
            Last Name:
            <input type="text" name="lastName"><br><br>
            Student ID:
            <input type="text" name="studentID"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Register Student"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="reset" value="Clear Form">

        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <div id="duetSelected" style="display: none">
        <form id="myForm1" action="" onsubmit="validateForm()">
            <fieldset>
                First Name:
                <input type="text" name="firstName"><br><br>
                Last Name:
                <input type="text" name="lastName"><br><br>
                Student ID:
                <input type="text" name="studentID"><br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Register Student"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="reset" value="Clear Form">

            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
```

And this is what I have in my javascript file:

```
function validateForm()
{
    var a = document.forms["myForm"]["firstName"].value;
    var b = document.forms["myForm"]["lastName"].value;
    var c = document.forms["myForm"]["studentID"].value;

    if (a == "" || b == "" || c == "")
    {
        alert("First name, last name and Student ID must be filled.");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }

    $("input[type='radio'][id='duet']").on("change",function()
    {
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            $("#duetSelected").show();
        }
        else
        {
           $("#duetSelected").hide();
    }
  });

}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$("input[type='radio'][id='duet']")`, just use `$('#duet')`.  The id shouldn't be duplicated on anything else.  The radio filter is unnecessary and doing an id look up with an attribute selector doesn't let you get the performance gains that just looking up by id will.  Also `$(this).is(':checked')` can be just `this.checked`.  Checked is a property.

Comment: Also, 'change' for radio buttons only fires for the radio button that is being selected.  So the not checked conditional in your event handler doesn't make sense.

Comment: I would also move your listener out of your validateForm function.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Also, I wanted to display the second form as soon as duet is selected. Should I put the verification outside of validateForm()? And it is calling that function ony on onsubmit(), should I put it somewhere else?

Comment: Your JavaScript also doesn't appear to have the `checkType()` function that is called in your HTML.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that. I was going to try something but I changed my mind and forgot to delete that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first you have to put out the function for the radio outside the submit function.

I erase the return true because by logic if is not false, is true, and valid the id when change the radio button.

Hope it works for you!

https://codepen.io/mackiechan/pen/dZBzEa

```js
function validateForm()
{
    var a = document.forms["myForm"]["firstName"].value;
    var b = document.forms["myForm"]["lastName"].value;
    var c = document.forms["myForm"]["studentID"].value;

    if (a == "" || b == "" || c == "")
    {
        alert("First name, last name and Student ID must be filled.");
        return false;
    }
}

$("input[type=radio]").on("change",function()
    {
      var thisid = $(this).attr('id');
        if(thisid==='duet')
        {
            $("#duetSelected").show();
        }else{
          $("#duetSelected").hide();
        }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" action="" onsubmit="validateForm()">
        <fieldset>
            Performance Type:
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="performanceType" id="solo" value="Solo">Solo<br>
            <input type="radio" name="performanceType" id="duet"  value="Duet">Duet<br>
            <input type="radio" name="performanceType" id="concerto" value="Concerto">Concerto<br><br>
            First Name:
            <input type="text" name="firstName"><br><br>
            Last Name:
            <input type="text" name="lastName"><br><br>
            Student ID:
            <input type="text" name="studentID"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Register Student"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="reset" value="Clear Form">

        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <div id="duetSelected" style="display: none">
        <form id="myForm1" action="" onsubmit="validateForm()">
            <fieldset>
                First Name:
                <input type="text" name="firstName"><br><br>
                Last Name:
                <input type="text" name="lastName"><br><br>
                Student ID:
                <input type="text" name="studentID"><br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Register Student"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="reset" value="Clear Form">

            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: I tried that but it won't display the second form to me. When I check the console, it says "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at week12.js:14"

Comment: Are you calling the jquery library?

Comment: Yeah I put <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> in the <head> tag

Comment: Are you executing the function for the radio button, after the jquery script? maybe you need to add the document ready before this

Comment: Like this: jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$("input[type='radio']").on("change",function()
    {
      var thisid = $(this).attr('id');
        if(thisid==='duet' && $(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            $("#duetSelected").show();
        }else{
          $("#duetSelected").hide();
        }
  });
});

Comment: Yes, after. Do you mean do it like this?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type=radio]").on("change",function()
    {
      var thisid = $(this).attr('id');
        if(thisid==='duet')
        {
            $("#duetSelected").show();
        }else{
          $("#duetSelected").hide();
        }
  });
});

Comment: It keeps saying uncaught reference: $ is not defined

Comment: Use Google CDN for fast loading:

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>